# Getting NullPointer Exception when declaring LinkedBlockingQueue<String>

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, queue

This is the code I have. I have getting Null Pointer Exception in the last line of the constructor (workerQueue[i] = new LinkedBlockingQueue(100);):

```
public class QueueThreadPool {

  private BlockingQueue<String>[] workerQueue;
  private Thread[] workerThreads;
  private int numQueues;
  private int numThreads;

public QueueThreadPool(int numThreads, int numQueues) {
    this.numQueues = numQueues;
    this.numThreads = numThreads;

    for(int i=1; i<=numQueues; i++){
        workerQueue[i] = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(100);
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Start...");
    new QueueThreadPool(50, 11);
    System.out.println("End...");
}
```

Please help!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array `workerQueue` is not instantiated which you need to do.

```
private BlockingQueue<String>[] workerQueue;
```

`workerQueue` is a reference of `BlockingQueue<String>[]` type, not a Object.

*But also you cannot create a generic array of `BlockingQueue<String>`*. Instead of that create a `List` of `BlockingQueue<String>`. Ex -

```
private List<BlockingQueue<String>> workerQueue= new ArrayList<>();
```

you can also create the list Object at constructor.

```
private List<BlockingQueue<String>> workerQueue= new ArrayList<>();
public QueueThreadPool(int numThreads, int numQueues) {
    this.workerQueue = new ArrayList<>(numQueues);  // <-- initialize the field.
    this.numQueues = numQueues;
    this.numThreads = numThreads;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `workerThreads`. You have to do something like `workerQueue= new BlockingQueue<String>[numQueues];`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned int he ab ove answer, this declaration creates a generic array, which again gives error.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in the code: the field need to be initialized, the loop should go from 0 to the array-size's - 1. Here is how the fixed code should look like:

```
public class QueueThreadPool {

  private BlockingQueue<String>[] workerQueue;
  private Thread[] workerThreads;
  private int numQueues;
  private int numThreads;

public QueueThreadPool(int numThreads, int numQueues) {
    this.workerQueue = new BlockingQueue<String>[numQueues]  // <-- You need to initialize the field.
    this.numQueues = numQueues;
    this.numThreads = numThreads;

    for(int i=0; i < numQueues; i++){  // <-- Indexing into arrays goes from 0 to size-1     (inclusive).
        workerQueue[i] = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As mentioned in the above answer, this declaration creates a generic array, which again gives error.